# Нужно взять с url, то что написал в input

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

**Проблема в том, что req.params.title это "search", а нужно то, что написал в input**

form в pug:

```
form.header__block-search-content(action="/search" method="GET")
     span.header-search-word Поиск
     input.header-search.header-search-show(type="text" name="text")
```

ее обработка:

```
router.get('/:title', async(req, res) => {
    const title = req.params.title;

    const products = await Product.find({ title })
        .select('nowPrice oldPrice sale sizes img mainSize description sex article accessories');

    res.render('shop', {
        title: `Ryc-store ${title}`,
        products: products,
        isShop: true
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.post('/search', (req, res) => {
    const { text } = req.query;
    console.log(`[search] ${text}`);
    res.json({ok: true});
});

app.get('/search/:title', (req, res) => {
    const { title } = req.params;
    console.log(`[search] ${title}`);
    res.json({ok: true});
});

app.listen(3003, 'localhost');
```

Первый роут правильно обработает вашу форму, а вот для того, чтобы сработал роут с именованным параметром, нужно сделать такой запрос:

`curl 'http://localhost:3003/search/карамба'`

Comment: А где и как мы делаем post запрос (форма)? Соответственно ошибка: Cannot GET /search.

Comment: просто поменял post на get и заработало. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

то что в input можно достать через onChange и event.target.value примерно таким образом (пример из синтаксиса react, но и на vanilla js можно переложить):

```
<Input
 type='email'
 placeholder='Введите email'
 id='email'
 value={props.email}
 onChange={(e) => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
/>
```

ответ достоин, разве что, комментария, но у меня кармы не хватает

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что мне нужно это значение - бадлон женский из url - localhost:8888/search?text=бадлон+женский